# One of two background images broken only on iOS device

Tags: css, html

I'm completely stumped. This issue has wasted too many of my hours.

I have two backgrounds with parallax scrolling - work 'almost' perfectly. Adding responsiveness to the website for mobile phones. If I use chromes mobile simulator, works on every device perfectly. If I use it on an android phone, perfectly... however on iOS, the first background-image is applies however the second is not visible whatsoever. All you see is the content and a white background. It makes no sense at all, considering they have identical settings - I've tried renaming the image, changing the image file type, using the same image as in background-1 and none of it works. I've tried deleting pretty much my whole codebase to try and debug it from bottom to top - nothing achieved. The only noticeable thing was if I completely removed .background-1, then a fraction of the background image of .background-2 shows - despite its height being 100vh.

Sum it up: works on simulator perfectly, android phone perfectly - iphone one of the two almost identical divs work.

```css
.background-1 {
  background-image: url("image1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.background-2 {
  background-image: url("image2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-blend-mode: lighten;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="background-1"> </div>

<div class="information">This div contains some information.....</div>

<div class="background-2"></div>
```

Comment: `background-position: top` might do. It reminds me of some IE6 bugs and bg attachment

Comment: unfortunately that didn't do anything, thanks for the response though :) @GCyrillus

Comment: too bad,it  seemed too easy on the other hand :(

Comment: @GCyrillus quick question as you're clearly more experienced than me, do you recommend I continue trying to find a solution for this or move onto something else - because I'm learning very little/losing a-lot of time on it. But at the same time, it's a pretty important aspect of the UI =/

Comment: I'd suggested :  - switch image background (maybe something about the image itself with the wrong extension or bad datas) - try bottom for position, -  to search for a known bug, if it is already reported it  might be a known work around, then move onto something else . My guess bg-position is buggy there.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat of an answer - The image is now visible

reference: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/parallax-on-mobile/

Adding background-attachment: scroll; seemed to do the trick.